# NodeMailer - Transport option must be a transport instance or configuration object

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, email-templates

I am trying to create a email verification mailer following the example from [here](https://www.codementor.io/joshuaaroke/sending-html-message-in-nodejs-express-9i3d3uhjr). I added both `email-template` and `nodemailer` packages. I made the `transporter` available as an adapter throughout my application. Below is the code for `mailer.ts`:

```
import * as mailer from 'nodemailer';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.load({ path: '.env' });

var mailConfig = {
    host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
    }
};

var transporter = mailer.createTransport(mailConfig);

module.exports = transporter;
```

I am trying to build a wrapper around `email-template` like below `signup.ts`:

```
const EmailTemplate = require('email-templates');
var mailer = require('../mailer');

var sendEmailVerficationLink = mailer.templateSender(
    new EmailTemplate({
        views: { root: './verify' }
    }), {
        from: process.env.MAIL_FROM,
    });

exports.sendVerficationLink = function (obj) {
    sendEmailVerficationLink({
        to: obj.email,
        subject: 'Verify your Email'
    }, {
            name: obj.username,
            token: obj.otp
        }, function (err, info) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log('Sign up mail sent to ' + obj.email + ' for verification.');
            }
        });
};
```

In my actual controller, I try to send the mail as below `user.ts`:

```
var verify = require('../utils/mailer-templates/signup');
signup = (req, res) => {
    ..
    verify.sendVerficationLink(obj); // send the actual user object
    ..
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Transport option must be a transport instance or configuration object
[1]     at new Email (C:\Users\User\Documents\Vivavii-REST\node_modules\email-templates\lib\index.js:82:83)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Vivavii-REST\dist\utils\mailer-templates\signup.js:3:54)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
[1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
[1]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
[1]     at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
[1]     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
[1]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Vivavii-REST\dist\controllers\user.js:14:14)
[1]     at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
[1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
[1]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
[1]     at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main issue** You used outdated example. In the example *nodemailer* has 2.7.2 version and unknown *email-templates*. Current *nodemailer* version is 4.4.1.

In the latest *email-templates* version you don't need directly work with *nodemailer*. You can pass configuration in transport params. Here is fixed version of your code:

```
const EmailTemplate = require('email-templates');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.load({ path: '.env' });

const emailTemplate = new EmailTemplate({
    message: {
        from: process.env.MAIL_FROM
    },
    transport: {
        host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
        port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
        auth: {
            user: process.env.MAIL_USERNAME,
            pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
        }
    }
});

function sendVerficationLink(obj) {
    return emailTemplate.send({
        template: 'verify',
        message: {
            to: obj.email
        },
        locals: {
            name: obj.username,
            token: obj.otp
        }
    });
};

exports.sendVerficationLink = sendVerficationLink;
```

Some details:

- `mailer.ts` is redundant
- in project there is folder emails with templates. More [infomation](https://github.com/niftylettuce/email-templates)

Comment: I changed `exports.sendVerificationLink` to `exports.module = (varname)` and tried to import in another module but I am getting `it is not a module` error. Can you please help?

Comment: I don't know why you do this. But could you try to change to
`module.exports.sendVerificationLink`?

Also, I have guess that, you try work with ECMAScript 6 modules (import/export) instead commonjs modules (require/module.export). I wrote my example with commonjs module approach, so you need `const sendVerficationLink = require('./example');`.
Chose one approach and use it in whole project for avoiding such errors.